# Using Javascript object in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a simple quiz in Javascript and want to display it in an HTML page. I cut and pasted the Javascript object with the questions and answers into the head of the HTML.

My question is how can I display each question with it's choices and then when I click the "Next" button the next question will come up?

I also have some logic to add in which calculates score on the quiz but that is for another question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>The quiz</title>
        <script>
        var questions = [{question: "Whos the best bball player?", choices: ["Lebron James", "Kobe Bryant", "Kevin Durant", "Javale McGee"], correctAnswer:0},
        {question: "Name the Miami Heat player?", choices: ["Camelo Anthony", "Kevin Love", "Paul Pierce", "Dwayne Wade"], correctAnswer:3},
        {question: "Name the LA Lakers player?", choices: ["Lebron James", "Kobe Bryant", "Kevin Durant", "Javale McGee"], correctAnswer:1},
        {question: "What team does Melo play for?", choices: ["Chicago Bulls", "Utah Jazz", "New York Knicks", "Orlando Magic"], correctAnswer:2}
        ];
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <section>
            <h1>Welcome to the quiz!<h1>

            <form name="quiz">
                <label for="choice">QUESTION HERE</label>
                <br><input type="radio" name="choice" value="1">CHOICE HERE</input>
                <br><input type="radio" name="choice" value="2">CHOICE HERE</input>
                <br><input type="radio" name="choice" value="3">CHOICE HERE</input>
                <br><input type="submit" value="Next">
            </form>

        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It require some more work. You just try it. and come back when you stuck at some point.

Comment: If I'm doing something wrong let me know. Negative votes don't really help much guys. This is my first time using Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok since you're new to JavaScript, here's a little complete code I'm writing. 
First you don't need any form when all your data is static. So just replace your entire Form block with following

```
<label for="choice" id="question">QUESTION HERE</label>
<br><input type="radio" id='choice1' name="choice" value="1">CHOICE HERE</input>
<br><input type="radio" id="choice2" name="choice" value="2">CHOICE HERE</input>
<br><input type="radio" id="choice3" name="choice" value="3">CHOICE HERE</input>
<br><button id="next">Next</button>
```

Now just include a separate JavaScript file or write following code below the HTML declaration in script tag.

```
var questions = [{question: "Whos the best bball player?", choices: ["Lebron James", "Kobe Bryant", "Kevin Durant", "Javale McGee"], correctAnswer:0},
    {question: "Name the Miami Heat player?", choices: ["Camelo Anthony", "Kevin Love", "Paul Pierce", "Dwayne Wade"], correctAnswer:3},
    {question: "Name the LA Lakers player?", choices: ["Lebron James", "Kobe Bryant", "Kevin Durant", "Javale McGee"], correctAnswer:1},
    {question: "What team does Melo play for?", choices: ["Chicago Bulls", "Utah Jazz", "New York Knicks", "Orlando Magic"], correctAnswer:2}];

var index = 0;
var totalLength = questions.length;

$("#next").on("click", function() {
    if(index < totalLength) {
        var questionObject = questions[index];
        $("#question").text(questionObject.question);
        $("#choice1").text(questionObject.choices[0]);
        $("#choice2").text(questionObject.choices[1]);
        $("#choice3").text(questionObject.choices[2]);
        index++;
    }
});
```

As you can see whenever you can click the button, the next question if available in array, will be shown in the page.

Answer (score 0):

First:

that not an object. that an array.

```
arr = [1,2,3];
obj = {a:1,b:2,c:3};
```

Second:

the interaction between JS and HTML is throw DOM.
meaning you gonna have to write your own function to interact with the inner html between tags.

simple method to do that is to use jquery which really help to navigate in the DOM.

another method is to write your own JS.

if you want snippet of doing that **Without** jQuery let me know.

Hope it helps.

**Edit:**

first you wanna go here: [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

and there have a little learning about interaction with HTML.
you will wanna also open Developer tools on your Chrome bowser and open console.

now try to write document (it will complete it) and then dot, and the it will suggest ton of functions to interact with the document itself.

maybe i will have time later, i will write you a snippet.

also please try looking in google for q-and-a JS frameworks. im sure there is a lot.

Comment: Whoops I meant array of objects with each question being an object. Yeah I want to try and do it without jQuery for now. Could you show me a really simple example even if it doesn't use my quiz thanks!

Comment: are you programmer in some language?

Answer (score 0):

You may find that it's A better approach may be to write this totally in Javascript. Put your questions and handling in a separate JS file and write some JQuery to populate the questions label and choices using the [JQuery Text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/), use the Val function to get answer back [JQuery val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) and take a look a AJAX to send it back to the server [JQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) using a POST. All of these have examples to get you further towards a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the limited of time and unsure of what exactly you are looking for, I created a simple guide which you can have a play: http://jsfiddle.net/yht3A/

Actually you can write all your questions in just plain HTML and wrap each question with a div, I'm sure you know how to make them show one by one with jquery, not sure if you want to display choice or answer so I did kind of both.

You can use radio or dropdown selection for answers, doesn't.

Form structure looks like this:

```
<form name="quiz">
    <div class="question" id="quiz-1" data-answer="Lebron James">
         <h1>1. Whos the best bball player?</h1>
        <ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Lebron James" />Lebron James</li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Kobe Bryant" />Kobe Bryant</li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Kevin Durant" />Kevin Durant</li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Javale McGee" />Javale McGee</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="question" id="quiz-2" data-answer="Camelo Anthony">
         <h1>2. Name the Miami Heat player?</h1>
        <ul style="margin-top: 1pt">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="Camelo Anthony" />Camelo Anthony</li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="q1" value="Kevin Love" />Kevin Love</li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="Paul Pierce" />Paul Pierce</li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" name="q2" value="Dwayne Wade" />Dwayne Wade</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```